# Why does my cat lick her belly until sore?

Tags: cats, grooming, skin-condition

Hi I’m wondering if anyone can help me because I’m at a serious loss and I don’t know what to do. It’s really frustrating because I have been to the vets constantly over the past two years, to three different vets and nobody can tell me what’s wrong with her :(.

I believe after researching online that she’s participating in something called mowing. But all the pictures I’ve seen are no where near as bad as hers. She began grooming her back leaving bald patches like the mowing but she’s now moved to her belly and it gets so bad that as you can see in the picture, she will bite and cut herself. I have literally tried everything. She does not have fleas. Mites. Ringworm. Anything like that. The most recent visit to the vets ruled out any infection or parasites. They gave her steroid tablets but it’s done nothing to help her grooming. I’ve changed her food several times from when this started (although someone suggested wet food so I may give this a go). We’ve bought a special brush to help remove dead hair and skin so she doesn’t feel the need to groom as much but that hasn’t helped. Although we get little flakes of skin that look like dandruff come out, has anyone had an experience with this? Maybe it’s like a cat eczema or something? She’s settled, gets on with our other cat and there’s no reason she’d be stressed. We have treated her for this in the past, we were given meidication and it’s still happening. We’ve now had to result in putting a cone on until it scabs over and settles but it’s so horrible to see her like it.

I literally don’t know what else I can do. Every time I go to the vets they either don’t know, don’t find anything or subscribe her medication thats innappropriate and I don’t want to keep medicating her when it’s not an accurate diagnosis.

Any suggestions advise or experience would be HUGELY appreciated

[image]

Comment: this is related https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/8046/why-does-my-cat-lick-the-fur-off-her-lower-belly maby the answer can help you.your question is a duplicate as i have seen it before on this site.

Comment: This post is what I was referring to about the wet food/pictures ect....but like I said she doesn’t simply groom the hair off it’s a real issue and I have already tried all of the things suggested on there (explained in my original post) I posted as I thought maybe it was linked to something else and someone may have different advise for me. Trond I have looked at you libknand this could be more to what she’s experiencing thank you